# Protractor: Reducing Zoom value in google chrome from 100% to 80% during execution

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

```
onPrepare:function(){
    browser.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='80%'");
}
```

Here i am trying to reduce zoom from 100% to 80%. I have used above code in config file, which is not working. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular approach would only work *after you've navigated to a page*:

```
browser.get("url");
browser.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='80%'");
```

Comment: Hey @alexce .. I was also wondering why this is working only after `browser.get()` ..  I checked even the document.readystate in `onprepare()` and it was `complete`.. Is there any reason why this doesnt work in `\onPrepare()`

Comment: @AdityaReddy yeah, I think this is chromedriver specific but I could not find a way to prove it. Thanks.